# Classes calling methods from other classes

Tags: intellij-idea, arraylist

I have got a several different classes under the same package in intellij idea,the problem is classes cannot recognize the other class' methods and throws cannot resolve symbol, have tried invalidating cache and restarting to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find that people here are very good at answering questions about programming, but in general they lack mind reading capabilities. Good starting points to overcome this is to read these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

The question is prety unclear but I will try to guess what the problem is.

Have you marked the root folder of your project as **sources root** folder?  This should help intellij to recognize the classes as one project. It should be done from:

```
right click over the folder -> mark directory as -> sources root.
```

When done the folder icon will be colored in blue and intellij should recognize the module(project) structure